# SQL to bulk edit all post from specific author?

Tags: sql, wordpress, categories

I've been looking around many google results and answers here without luck.

I need to remove and add categories to posts by a specific author using a SQL statement.

I assume logically I would do the following:

- select all posts with author ID
- delete all current category IDs assigned to those posts.
- add new category ID(s) to those posts.

Can someone assist with the syntax of the statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of delete then adding in two separate steps, the update function will do it in one step.

what you need to is then simply

```
UPDATE Table1 
 SET category_ID = newID 
  WHERE author_id = "14567"
```